# jQuery Callback of function inside on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function fileUploadHandler that I pass as a parameter in .on() like this:

```
$('#image_upload').on('change', fileUploadHandler);
```

I want to assign a callback to fileUploadHandler so that it runs as soon as the above completes. I've tried several things, such as:

```
fileUploadHandler(event, function() {
        // code to run as callback
    }
});
```

but I can't figure out how to get the callback to run instantly after fileUploadHandler runs and the on change is complete.

To elaborate further:

fileUploadHandler contains code to do several image-cropping operations, including nested AJAX calls (probably can be organized cleaner, but either way). I am trying to obtain the values of the width and height HTML attributes using:

```
$(".cr-image").attr("width") and $(".cr-image").attr("height")
```

However, since those values are populated using other JS libraries, running the above attr methods gives me undefined instead of the values, which I'm assuming can be fixed by running attr after the operations in fileUploadHandler run. But at the same time, fileUploadHandler is itself a callback to .on('change')

Comment: give us exact process of this code? what it needs to do

Comment: Okay, updated question.

Comment: so you want another function to run as soon as ajax is finished? ajax is asynchronous so you can use call back there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fileUploadHandler is the 'callback' function, or rather event handler, that will be called when your change event happens.

```
function fileUploadHandler (event) {
    // code that runs when the change event is fired.
    // $(event.currentTarget) will be the element that triggered the event
}
$('#image_upload').on('change', fileUploadHandler);
```

if for some reason you need to be a bit more complex, you could try

```
function fileUploadHandler(callback, event) {
    // do stuff with the event/element here
    $.ajax('/foo.php').then(callback);


}
function followupCallback(response) {
    console.log(response); 
    // do your processing here using the server responses.
}
$('#image_upload').on('change', fileUploadHandler.bind(this, followupCallback));
```

Comment: Yes, but what I mean is, I want a callback for fileUploadHandler itself to run when fileUploadHandler runs its own code.

Comment: fileUploadHandler will just run as a normal function.  Add any code you want to execute at the end of it.  No need for fancy callbacks.

Comment: Just updated my question, please have a look at the question again.

Comment: Using your help, I did figure out my problem, but in a variant implementation. I did have to use .then() and it worked. Thank you.